# Running vi mode on the command line in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, linux-mint

I have `set -o vi` set in my .bashrc, and it runs great generally, but when I run tmux it doesn't work.  Below are my .tmux.conf contents.

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
# bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection-and-cancel

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
```

Any ideas what I can do to change this?  I'm running Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia.

Answer (score 1):

was answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320465/new-tmux-sessions-do-not-source-bashrc-file/541352) via adding `source "$HOME/.bashrc"` to .bash_profile